# How to send base64 encoded image string into JSON object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, base64

I wanted to convert a image file into JSON object in javascript.
So I have converted image into a string using base64 encoding.
How to convert this string to JSON object?

Comment: This question is already asked ultiple times over here why you isnt search for it ?

Comment: Did you mean put this base64 string into a JSON object to post data?

Comment: yes, base64 string into JSON object to post data.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, set value to an keyObj.

```
    var base64String = 'data:image/png;base64....'
    var imgObj = {
      url: base64String
    }

    <img src=''+ imgObj.url +''/>
```

Comment: can access to the properties of the image file(height , width,etc..) with this code? If not how to do that.

Comment: @SharathBhat yes, with `document.getElementById('#image-id').clientHeight` or `document.getElementById('#image-id').clientWidth` for example.

Comment: I have tried this code with `.obj` file, but it's unsucessful. The `base64String` of `.obj` file look like: `data:;base64.....`. Could you please give me some suggestion? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new Image() and set the src to the image.  Then onload of the image, draw it to a canvas (which can be in memory, doesn't need to be in the DOM), and from there use toDataURL().  See this page for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL